# Confusion with $\mathbb E[f(X,Y)]$, is it $\iint_{\Omega ^2}f(X,Y)d\mathbb Pd\mathbb P$?

Tags: probability

I'm confuse about $\mathbb E[f(X,Y)]$. So let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space and $X,Y$ two real random variable. What is $\mathbb E[f(X,Y)]$ ? Is it $$\mathbb E[f(X,Y)]=\int_\Omega \int_\Omega f(X,Y)d\mathbb Pd\mathbb P ?$$ 
If yes, I don't really see how to arrive to $$\iint_{\mathbb R^2}xy\mu_{X,Y}(dx\times dy)$$
where $\mu_{X,Y}$ is the conjoint density.

Answer (score 3):

As far as $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ is nice enough (for example, a Borel function), then $f(X,Y)$ is a random variable $\Omega \to \mathbb R$ (and not from $\Omega ^2\to \mathbb R$ as you seem to think). So, $$\mathbb E[f(X,Y)]=\int_\Omega  f(X,Y)\,\mathrm d \mathbb P.$$

Then, you get $$\mathbb E[f(X,Y)]=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}f(x,y)\mu_{X,Y}(dx\times dy),$$
where $$\mu_{X,Y}(dx,dy)=\mathbb P\{X\in dx,Y\in dy\}.$$